# responsive layout for all devices using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="jumbotron vertical-center bgpurpletextoffwhite"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
              <img src="./assets/images/pmflogo-transparent.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
             <br>
                <h3>Put Me First </h3>
            </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

this is my code. i want it to be responsive for all devices, but is not behaving responsive at present. the distance between image & text is changing as i resize the browser window. i want that disatnce to remain fixed throughout for every device/size

Comment: please create a fiddle with your code and that would be really cool if you include the picture of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Try adding the image responsive class to your image http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: have already added the image responsive class, but to no avail. the distance between the image & text changes as i resize the browser

Comment: the link for the image that i have used is- http://s30.postimg.org/ozhb3rw8t/pmflogo.png

Comment: Added screenshot 
http://imgur.com/P321O8C